# Principle of etremal aging

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

Say I'm in a region of space time where there is nothing and all of a sudden a star and a planet appeared out of nowhere ( for reference sake) is it due to the principle of extremal aging that the two will start to gravitate towards each other even though there is no net force acting upon them? If this is true I'm just confused as to why this would happen What starts the whole process if there is no movement ie) both objects are static?

Comment: I think that that the answer is that the principle relates to trajectories in spacetime. Even a stationary object "moves" through spacetime: it follows the time axis

Comment: *Etremal*?  (Makes me uncomfortable.)

Comment: So "how" objects start motion if both are static is due to the fact although an object can stand still in space it does not stand still in time? And that gives rise to relativistic motion?

Answer (score 0):

Usually physics does not answer "why" questions. It just describes how the universe behaves.

In classical physics, the force of gravity is given by $F = GmM/r^2$. The two objects attract because the forces are toward each other.

General relativity does provide more insight into how gravity works. You can derive general relativity from some simpler assumptions such as energy is conserved and others. It gives some information about how gravity works, but it is longer than a single post. I would suggest getting a book or Googling.

The short answer is that matter curves space-time, and curved space-time deflects matter from a straight line. But that isn't very satisfactory all by itself.